# Why does $E(e^{t(X + Y)}) = E(e^{tX})E(e^{tY})$?

Tags: probability

I roll a fair, 6-sided dice twice. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the outcomes of my first and second rolls. I subsequently find the moment generating function of $S = X + Y$ by finding $E(e^{t(X+Y)})$.

Why does $E(e^{t(X + Y)}) = E(e^{tX})E(e^{tY})$? I can see how $E(e^{t(X + Y)}) = E(e^{tX}e^{tY})$, but why can we just separate this expression into the product of two expected values?

Comment: Because $X$ and $Y$ are assuned independent. If not, that separation would NOT be possible! It is a general theorem that for independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ then $\mathrm{E} (XY) = \mathrm{E(X) \mathrm{E}(Y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do it because of **independence**.

Comment: So in general, if random variables $A$ and $B$ are independent, $E(AB) = E(A)E(B)$. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is very important fact about independence. The result does not go the other way. If $E(UV)=E(U)E(V)$, then $U$ and $V$ are *uncorrelated*, but not necessarily independent.

Comment: Although I think the identity in _some_ cases holds when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.